# SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition - Unable to connect

Tags: sql-server-2014

I just installed SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition on my Windows 10 computer. When installing, I chose both windows and SQL Server authentication and used a named instance called `MSSQLSERVER`. After installing I rebooted and made sure that the service is running. However, when I brought up Management Studio and tried to connect to this instance I got an error about being unable to connect. I tried using both window authentication as well as SQL Server authentication using the account and password I specified during installation.

I then brought up Computer Management and made sure that SQL Server for `MSSQLServer` is running. Finally I brought up SQL Server Configuration manager and made sure that Named Pipes and TCP/IP protocols are enabled.

What am I missing? Any ideas or recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What was the exact error message or code? Your question was lengthy, however, you omitted the most important part.

Comment: `MSSQLSERVER` is the default service name for the **default** / un-named instance. Have you tried connecting just to `.` or `(local)` ? WIthout mentioning the "instance" name ....

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! I was able to connect using "." and "(local)" and it opened immediately! So was my mistake in choosing "MSSQLSERVER" for my instance name? When I look at the server name in Object Explorer it says "(SQL Server 12.0.4213.0 - Desktop\Kevin". Does this mean that it ignored the name "MSSQLSERVER" that I typed as the instance name because I stupidly chose the name that it uses for the service? Should I leave it like this or should I re-install using a different name?

Comment: No, leave it as it is, MSSQLSERVER is the instance name given to the default instance, if you install it this way, you don't need to specify the instance name in your connections, Desktop\Kevin is most likely your computer and user name, object explorer tells you who you've connected as.

Comment: OK, I will leave it alone. It appears to be working correctly. Thanks again you guys for your help!